# Confused about Tensorflow Algorithm function

Tags: tensorflow

[Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15Cyy2H7nT40sGR7TBN5wBvgTd57mVKay#forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true&scrollTo=-lcnwG0VXF5h)

Under the section on Feature Columns, there is this specific line of code

```
feature_columns = [ ]
 for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    vocabulary = dftrain[feature_name].unique()
```

I'm struggling to understand what this is doing. I don't really know what to search up too as I'm still quite new to programming. Why is there a need for this line? I understand that it outputs all unique values of the specified feature_name, but don't get how it's linked to the next line.

Comment: If what you don't understand is "how it's linked to the next line", then shouldn't you also show the next line?

Comment: It's looping over the categorical features and then setting the vocabulary to the unique values in that particular column as a list. But the code in the notebook already explains what is being done.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't understand a function just google the module name (TensorFlow) and the function name. I found the documentation for `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list). To quote the documentation:

> Use this when your inputs are in string or integer format, and you have an in-memory vocabulary mapping each value to an integer ID. By default, out-of-vocabulary values are ignored.

What this section of code is doing is going through each column and mapping each unique string value to a unique integer (its location in the vocabulary list). Transforming your column using this type of mapping is common for categorical data. The reason that `unique` is needed is because `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` needs a unique list as an argument before it can work its magic.

In the future please put all necessary code in the question. It should not be required to visit another link to answer your question.